# Invoke "git bisect run <script>" from a shell script containing the bisect script, too

Tags: bash, git, git-bisect

I working on Git now and having a big problem.
The command `git bisect run` needs to be like that:

```
$ git bisect run <my_script> $arguments
```

But I need to work with `git bisect run` only in one script.
I know that my solution with 2 scripts works but I can't find a way to combine them.
What can I do that will resolve the problem?

I tried to use:

```
git bisect run sh -c
```

As example: In working on git and writing: `bash ../bisecter.sh 102`. When `bisecter.sh` is the name of the script and `102` is something we need to search in the commits. And this script I'm trying to write. With `bisect` and bash commands.

Comment: I have alot of commits and need to search something.
I know that if I do git bisect run <my_script> $arguments and sent it to my scrips (5 rows) it is finding the right commit.
But I need to do it in one script and just can't find the right answer for it.

Comment: Is there any command that replace "$ git bisect run <my_script> $arguments"
With "$ git bisect run ' the script itself ' "

Comment: Can you show what your "solution with 2 scripts" is?

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to write a script which invokes `git bisect run` and also contains the "second" script which needs to be passed as an argument?  I think most people use `git bisect run` interactively (via the keyboard, not invoking it via a script), so that may lead to confusion for readers of your question.

Comment: I can't show it because I am afraid that my professor will see it and he will say that I copied it from the Internet without knowing that it was me..

Comment: As example:
In working on git and writing: "bash ../bisecter.sh 102"
When bisecter.sh is the name of the script and 102 is something we need to search in the commits.
And this run the script I'm trying to write. With bisect and bash commends.

Comment: Do you have to use `git bisect`? What is the actual problem your professor gave you?

Comment: Yes, I have to.

Comment: I see that if I do echo "TEST_VALUE=$1" >> test.sh
then in test.sh I can see only: TEST_VALUE=102
How can I leave what is written as it is without it changing?

Answer (score 1):

You could check to see if the program is being run in "interactive mode" and run the appropriate command. If it's interactive, run `git bisect`.  If it isn't, you're being run by `git bisect`.

> An  interactive  shell  is  one  started without non-option arguments (unless -s is
> specified) and without the -c option whose standard input and error are  both  con-
> nected  to  terminals  (as  determined  by  isatty(3)),  or one started with the -i
> option.  PS1 is set and $- includes i if bash  is  interactive,  allowing  a  shell
> script or a startup file to test this state.

In bash you can check if [file descriptor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_descriptor) 1 (stdout) is outputting to a terminal.

```
if [ -t 1 ]; then
  echo "We're run from a shell, run git-bisect"
else
  echo "We're not run from a shell, do the bisecting."
fi
```

```
$ ./test.sh
We're run from a shell, run git-bisect

$ ./test.sh | cat
We're not run from a shell, do the bisecting.
```

But I seriously doubt that's what your professor intends you to do. ***The requirement to pass the same program to `git bisect` as runs `git bisect` doesn't make sense***. Either the professor has an odd requirement, a distinct possibility, or perhaps you've misunderstood how to solve the problem.

> When bisecter.sh is the name of the script and 102 is something we need to search in the commits.

[`git bisect`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect) is not for searching like that. It is for finding which commit caused a bug.

If you want to find which commit made a particular change, either in the log messages or in the changes, use [`git log -S`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Sltstringgt) or [`git log -G`](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Gltregexgt). That makes sense to do it in a single file.